# Assign a short name for a full directory path in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nutch

I am new on nutch. When I was installing nutch, I am stuck at line 
" ${NUTCH_RUNTIME_HOME} to refer to the current directory (apache-nutch-1.X/)".
Then How will I assign the variable name to current directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `~/.bashrc` ,
Add following lines at the end of the file:

```
# for example: 
# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export SHORT_NAME=/the/whole/directory
```

Run command `source .bashrc`

Then you can cd into `/the/whole/directory` by command `cd $SHORT_NAME`

This way works in bash =]

Comment: do we define user variable in /.bashrc  file and system variable in  /etc/environment file ?